# How do I set the value of HtmlOutputText in JSF?

Tags: forms, jsf, javabeans

I want to dynamically create a form with my bean. I am using JSF 2.0

```
HtmlOutputText htmlOutputText = new HtmlOutputText();
```

How should I set the content of HtmlOutputText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HtmlOutputText` extends `javax.faces.component.UIOutput`.

`UIOutput#setValue()` is the method you are looking for:

```
String value;
HtmlOutputText htmlOutputText = new HtmlOutputText();
htmlOutputText.setValue(value);
```

**Links**:

- [JavaServer Faces API (2.2)](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/javadocs/)